# how to parse JSON to an integer elements

Tags: json, rest, casting

By writing applications that inspires the problem. How do I parse `JSON` object (some are double types) are `Integer` objects?

This is a photo of my code:

[image]

The line of the casting error occurs:

> `java.lang.ClassCastException`: `java.lang.Double` cannot be cast to `java.lang.Integer`

How can I fix this?

Comment: Learn how to read an exception message.  The value you received is a Double, not an Integer.

Comment: And don't use images to show us code -- include the code in your post.  After you paste it into the question, highlight it and click the `{}` button above the edit window.

Comment: Try `Double.parseDouble(yourJsonStringObject)`

Comment: @SparkOn -- I don't think you know what JSON is.

Comment: A hint:  While you can cast a `double` primitive/scalar value to an `int` with `(int)`, you cannot cast a `Double` object reference to a `Integer` with `(Integer)`.  Casting a primitive and casting an object reference are two entirely different things.

Answer (score 0):

JSON only has a "number" data type... there is no distinction between double or int or any other type of number.  Your parser is thus playing it safe and assuming everything is a double.  You need an explicit cast if you want to convert the parser's double to an int.

Answer (score 0):

Insted of casting you can use `intValue()` because a double is not an integer.

```
Integer id_user = dataMap.get("id").intValue();
```